# Incorrectly reading int from binary file Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to read a date (set of 6 integers) and temperature (double) from binary .dat file.

After multiple tries I finally got to the stage where the file is working, but it's returning int in the format I cannot recognize. Eg. date 2017-03-02 11:33 , and temperature 3.8 is read as:

Measure : 515840-1024-1024 2816 8512 241591910 
temperature: 1.9034657819129845E185

Any ideas, how to change the code?

```
public void readFile() {

                try {
                    DataInputStream dis = null;
                    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
                    try {
                        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileLocation);

                        int b;
                        bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                        dis = new DataInputStream(fis);

                        while ((b = dis.read()) != -1) {

    System.out.println("Measure : " + dis.readInt() + "-" 
    + dis.readInt() + "-" + dis.readInt() + " " + 
    dis.readInt() + " " + dis.readInt() + " "
    + dis.readInt() + " Temperature: "+ dis.readDouble());

                        }
                    } finally {
                        dis.close();
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } catch (EOFException f) {
                    f.printStackTrace(); 
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } // readFile
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while ((b = dis.read()) != -1) {
```

The problem is here. This reads and discards a byte of the file on every iteration, so all subsequent reads are out of sync.

The correct way to loop with a `DataInputStream` or `ObjectInputStream` is with a `while (true)` loop, and terminating it when `read()` returns -1, `readLine()` returns `null`, or `readXXX()` for any other X throws `EOFException.`

Note that you don't normally need to log or print a stack trace on `EOFException`, as it's a normal loop termination condition ... *unless* you had reason to expect more data, e.g. your file started with a record count that you haven't reached yet, which might indicate that the file was truncated and therefore corrupt.